# When I try to execute popup, why is it throwing page not found error?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I can't figure out why this isn't working...

I've tried in a couple of different websites.  I'm thinking there might be something wrong with the script.

When run in the website, I get a 404 not found error.  The links on their own definitely work.

These have been tested in two different Wordpress sites.  I've tried the scripts in multiple locations, starting in header.

Script, then link

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function myPopup(url,windowname,w,h,x,y){
window.open(url,windowname,"resizable=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,status=no,directories=no,width="+w+",height="+h+",left="+x+",top="+y+"");
}
</script>
```

Link

```
<a href="myPopup('http://www.idogcam.com/idogcamviewerb.php?id=680', 'cam2','775','640','0','0')"> Outdoor Play 1</a><br />
<br />
```

Comment: In order for JS code to work in a `href` you need to prepend it with `javascript:`. Right now, the browser is trying to *navigate* to "myPopup(..."

Comment: Put `onclick` instead of `href`

Answer (score 1):

Best is to bind an event handler to the element as numerous other people have stated, however, do stuff works perfectly in every modern browser.

Also I prefer to use button for such things unless there is absolutely something compelling and doesn't allow a button (styled as link) to be used

```js
function myPopup(url,windowname,w,h,x,y){
window.open(url,windowname,"resizable=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,status=no,directories=no,width="+w+",height="+h+",left="+x+",top="+y+"");
}
```

```html
<a href ="#" onClick="myPopup('http://www.idogcam.com/idogcamviewerb.php?id=680', 'cam2','775','640','0','0')"> Outdoor Play 1</a><br />
<br />
```